# Livereload on android devices (chrome browser mainly)

Tags: javascript, macos, gruntjs

I recently got some new devices form the company on which i need to test responsivity.

I use grunt, and livereload plugin for sublime text + chrome. All I want is to make the nexus 7 tablet & galaxy3 & iphone5 devices to automatically reload the site upon i save the document.

One note, I work on a mounted ssh folder NOT on localhost. The grunt files are on localhost tho, and they are symlinked to the mounted folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use [`grunt-contrib-watch`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#optionslivereload) it should work out of the box. I've been doing it with my phone and some website development and it worked just fine most of the time.

Comment: hmm it seems like live reload function doesn't even works now. but i tested on localhost and it works as u said normally